# Is a downloaded OS X installer from the App Store tied to my Apple ID?

Tags: macos, install, apple-id, mac-appstore

At work I use an iMac which I'm going to have to reset to factory settings after my job ends. Since I only have access to slow, unstable internet, I thought it might save some time to download the El Capitan installer from the App Store in advance and [create a bootable installer drive](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372), rather than using [internet recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904).

After I (erase the drive and) use the bootable installer to reinstall the operating system, will the resulting installation be associated with my Apple ID in any way? Or more generally, will it have any personal information associated with me? I'd like to leave a completely fresh, un-personalized installation of OS X for whoever is going to use the computer next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by reinstall the OS, you simply mean reinstall it and not run first-time setup, the resulting installation will not be associated with you in any way.

If you intend to run first-time setup, obviously do not login with your Apple ID during that process, and of course don't input any personally-identifiable information either.

There is metadata in a receipt file in the installer file itself that is associated with your Apple ID. That is not transferred to the resulting installation, though.

Comment: OK, cool. That's not a problem for me as I don't expect to be sharing the installer file or the bootable drive with anyone. (And in any case, I don't need to _hide_ the fact that I was the last one to use the computer or that the installer was downloaded using my account.) Do you have a reference for your answer? It's a perfectly good answer without one, but I would like it even more with a link to documentation or something to back it up, if there is any official documentation on such things.

Comment: The only way for it to be associated with you is if you run first-time setup and enter your information (login with your Apple ID, etc) as this information is not carried in the installer. I don't have a reference other than having installed it myself.

Comment: The purchase info is stored in /Applications/Install OS X El Capitan.app/Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt (in an opaque format). I haven't checked, but I think you can remove that file and it'll still work. BTW I'd recommend saving the entire installer application, since I've seen installer disks get into weird states, and if you have the .app you can aways recreate the disk.

Comment: @GordonDavisson To clarify, I meant that it didn't carry all of your account information to automatically set it up once installed, as that was the OP's primary concern.

Comment: @tubedogg, The primary point of your answer, as written, is not necessarily true. While you did mention an important point in a comment, still part of the answer is not totally accurate. I'd suggest adding info from the comment to improve the overall accuracy of your answer. You might also want to incorporate Gordon Davisson comment. Here's an interesting page on [Poking Around in Mac App Store Receipts](https://magervalp.github.io/2013/03/19/poking-around-in-masreceipts.html). I confirmed my DSPersonID is stored in the _MASReceipt/receipt of the downloaded installer to remove any uncertainty.

Comment: @user3439894 Which part of my answer is not accurate? The receipt is in the _installer file_, not in the resulting installation. My answer says there is some metadata in the installer file associated with your Apple ID. The specific location of the metadata in the installer could be noted, but that part of the answer is really irrelevant anyway as the OP is concerned with _the resulting installation_ having his personal information. The only thing which could be construed as "not necessarily true" is my initial comment, which was not clear about what information was or wasn't in the installer.

Comment: @tubedogg, The first part, "_The resulting installation will not be associated with you in any way_" is only true if you do not create a login with your Apple ID, yes your said that in a comment and it should be apart of the answer, not left just in the comment alone. That is really way I was trying to communicate and I apologize for that not being clear, sorry.